# I'm trying to make fixed header change it's background-color after I scroll the page 100px

Tags: jquery, html, css, debugging

I was trying make a fixed header change it's background color after scrolling `100px` and again change back to default after I scroll back using the following jQuery:

here is my actual code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {

//After scrolling 100px from the top...
if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= 100 ) {
    $('#menu').css('background', '#fff');

//Otherwise remove inline styles and thereby revert to original stying
} else {
    $('#menu').removeAttr('style');

}
});​
</script>
</head>
<body>

<header>
<table>
<tr>
<td  id="menu" class="title">
    TITLE
</td>
<td style="width:40px;">
    <div class=" ico">    
    <img src="search.svg" alt="search" style="width: 25px;" />
    </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 40px;">
    <div class=" ico">
    <img src="menu.svg" alt="search" style="width: 25px;"/>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</header>
.
.
.
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone identify my problem?

Comment: Please give more meaningful titles to your questions.

Comment: What you have should work fine (although I would use `addClass` and `removeClass` respectively instead of removing the `style` attribute, and change `10` to `100`). Can you give us an example of the problem in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I set every thing fine but still it won't work. Can you give me a js code. I don't feel like using jq.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xwgo3e7j/1/ - This is a `position:fixed` element and it works fine...

Comment: lots of stuff missing to identify the problem. anyways. i created a JS fiddle with some working code that does exactly what you want. check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/RamiSarieddine/6yw6q1z3/

Comment: hey your code works great on jsfiddle but when i copy it to my editor( in a new page/file) it won't work. I'm sure my browser is up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 100) {
        jQuery('#menu').addClass('scrollActive');
    } else {
        jQuery('#menu').removeClass('scrollActive');
    }
});
```

and just add in your CSS

```
#menu.scrollActive {
  background-color: blue; // or color what you want;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 $(window).scrollTop() >= 10
```

to

```
  $(window).scrollTop() >= 100
```

Comment: It doesn't mater because it's doesn't work even if i change it to 100 or 1000. I think the problem is it's a fixed element any idea.

Comment: yeh just post the actuall code from my project head.

Comment: move your script  to the bottom of the page or wrap it with an onload function.