# How to make header color change, after scrolling down in site?

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my first question here. I have issue with making the header to change color after being scrolled down in homepage. I searched Stackoverflow archive, and found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088816/im-trying-to-make-fixed-header-change-its-background-color-after-i-scroll-the) but dont know how to make this working on [my site](http://deilbeatz.com/). Can someone to tell me how to integrate this ? Thanks

Comment: If the answer on the question you've referenced isn't clear enough I don't know how anyone can make it any clearer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your answer dont help me nothing..

Comment: Take the code from the link you gave, copy it into the template you call your website and you are done. Then go to your parents and ask them why they didn't teach you any manners. Paulie_D was trying to help you construct a good question.

Answer (score 0):

That is simple, just use this javascript:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll","myFunction");
function myFunction() {
  var myscroll = 200; // Replace this value with the height you want to scroll
                      // to change the header background
  var myheader = ; // your header selector here
  if (document.body.scrollTop > myscroll || document.documentElement.scrollTop > myscroll) {
    myheader.style.backgroundColor = "#40A824"; // Replace this with the
                                                // color you want after scrolling
  }
}
```